# Spring AOP pointcut not triggering

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, aspectj

For some reason, my pointcut is not triggered.
Note: I am using spring-style aspects, not AspectJ style.

**XML snippet**

```xml
<bean id="authenticationAspect" class="ssel.banking.security.AuthenticationAspect" />

<aop:config>
    <aop:aspect ref="authenticationAspect">
        <aop:pointcut id="interceptControllerInvocation"
            expression="execution(* org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.Controller+.handleRequestInternal(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest, ..)) 
                                      and args(request, ..) 
                                      and target(controller)"/>

        <aop:around pointcut-ref="interceptControllerInvocation" 
            method="authenticationAdvice"/>
    </aop:aspect>
</aop:config>
```

**Class defined by my bean**

```java
import org.aspectj.lang.ProceedingJoinPoint;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.Controller;

public class AuthenticationAspect {

    public ModelAndView authenticationAdvice(ProceedingJoinPoint pjp, HttpServletRequest request, Controller controller) throws Throwable{

        String URL = request.getRequestURL().toString();
        String viewName = URL.substring(0, URL.length() - 4);
        System.out.println(viewName);

        return (ModelAndView) pjp.proceed();
    }

}
```

Am I missing something?

Comment: Adding on to what Zoran Regvart said, if `handleRequestInternal` is not being called across a bean boundaries (i.e. it is being called from another method in the bean like `handleRequest` it won't be proxied because it is a reentrant call.

Answer (score 1):

Most probably invocation of handleRequestInternal method is not done across bean boundaries, but from the bean itself. I guess you're using AbstractController as a base for your controllers, and you can see that [handleRequest method](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.springframework/spring-webmvc/4.0.6.RELEASE/org/springframework/web/servlet/mvc/AbstractController.java#149) is calling handleRequestInternal directly.

You cannot instrument that code without using aspect compiler and change the class bytecode. And you probably don't want to do that with library code (AbstractController).